# How to use ffmpeg so that there would be no need in including its dlls in your app folder?

Tags: c++, c, windows, ffmpeg

So my point is to find normal ffmpeg in form of .lib for c/C++ windows developers so to be capable of including all needed functions inside my app - so to say one exe no extra dlls.

So I am looking thrue its windows [/autobuilds/](http://ffmpeg.arrozcru.org/autobuilds/) in search for such array of .lib files. as for now closest to what I wanted was that ffmpeg-swscale-mingw32-shared-dev\lib folder with .lib and .dll.a files. problem is I am quite new to C/C++ development so I wonder if this build is what I need or I need something else?

And what are .dll.a files for in ffmpeg mingw32 shared dev build after all?

Answer (score 4):

A shared build will depend on external DLLs, you need to find **static** built FFmpeg libraries so they will be linked to exe.

You will always need the following files:

**libavcodec.a**

**libavformat.a**

**libavutil.a**

There are also ***optional*** components depending on your code:

**libavfilter.a**

**libavdevice.a**

**libswscale.a**

Comment: could you provide a link to  static built of FFmpeg libraries, could you please explain what is relation between .lib and .a files?

Comment: *.lib files just contains definitions for exported symbols, its not needed for static linking. On the other hand according to http://ffmpeg.arrozcru.org/builds FFmpeg static libraries are having some problems, so you'll have to compile it by hand.

Answer (score 3):

You should be aware that if you intend to distribute a program linked to FFmpeg this way, you must either make your program free/opensource or at least distribute object files for your program so that end-users can re-link it with a modified version of FFmpeg. If you choose the latter option (i.e. if you don't want to make your program free software), you must be sure that your static FFmpeg library omits the optional GPL-licensed functionality, or your use will be infringing and the only way you will be able to get out of trouble is to release your entire program under a GPL-compatible license.

Comment: My app gona be opensource so no problem with that. Where to get static builts?